# Is there something like wamp.ws for WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

I am looking for **language agnostic** rpc plattform, which runs in the browser like wamp.ws and supports not only javascript. Something like wamp.ws, but running on top of webrtc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such product. Bindings of WebRTC for languages other than JS are just starting to emerge. Webrtc is typically used for messaging (send a message, get a message) although it can be used for RPC by adding an additional layer on top.